# LIVE EDIT google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, web-deployment

Being part of web development for a while now and I understand how environment set-up of your project takes time for you to debug your code from time to time.

Recently, months back, I discovered for myself that I can live edit in CHROME. This may be off topic but I wanted to know who else using live edit in Chrome and what they feels about the PROS and CONS of this feature from Chrome. What fixes you can suggest to fix in this feature?

Some I can think of:

The major help this feature provide is you can edit your JavaScript live, debug your code in browser, fix live and test there only.

I have noticed few of the cons

1. feature won't let you write new function live.
2. it's won't let you modify the selector
3. sometimes when you live edit you see console warning as "live edit failed.."

Are these fixable?
Can we suggest more of these based on our experience with using this feature?
Can we suggest to our feedback to Google chrome?

I was unable to find official page where docs related to what we can do and what we can not is mentioned.

Could you please guide me if there is any documentation part is available. what are PROS and CONS of Live Edit in Chrome?

Comment: Note that "Live Edit" feature is not only in Chrome, is in all mayor browsers since some years ago.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I am talking about js edit. Are other browsers support live js edit? Please enlight my knowledge

Comment: Oh, is not related with your question, is only a note. in firefox you have a Scratchpad (the same feature of chrome's snippets), and a console, and a debugger, and a css live editor....

Comment: Oh... okay..... I knew that :)... Any inputs for my question?